# How to display results of 1 channel in CIELab

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, image-processing

I need to display the output of b* channel(I have performed inverse Thresholding on b* channel). I am new to the OpenCv so I'm having hard time to figure out the method to do this, as if I directly used the Mat to Bitmap conversion on imgLab Mat, I face error... and I'm not sure how to copy the outputs of b* channel on oriImage Mat. Please help.

```
public void imageProcessingAlgorithm (){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                countWBC = 0;
                countRBC = 0;

                //Convert the Bitmap image to Mat
                //Utils.bitmapToMat converts an Android Bitmap to an OpenCV Mat.
                Mat oriImage = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(processBitmap, oriImage);
                //Imgproc.cvtColor(oriImage, oriImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

                //Grayscale image
                Mat grayscale = new Mat();
                Imgproc.cvtColor(oriImage,grayscale, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

                //Otsu Thresholding (Binary Image)
                Mat otsuThreshold = new Mat();
                Imgproc.threshold(grayscale, otsuThreshold ,0,255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

                //Contour finding
                List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(); //list for contours
                Imgproc.findContours(otsuThreshold, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
                //Mat drawing = new Mat(otsuThreshold.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

                Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                int xBound =0;
                int yBound =0;
                int xWidth =0;
                int yHeight =0;
                int radius = 0;

                for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                    Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
                    List<Double> areasList = new ArrayList<Double>(); //list for area
                    double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                    areasList.add(contourarea);
                    //Point2f means 2D coordinates
                    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
                    MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(idx).toArray());
                    double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * 0.02;
                    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);
                    MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());
                    rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);

                    //if the image is in the form of circular microscopic region, thus we need to crop it with ROI. if image contour>100000 it means the sample is already in square, so no need to crop
                    if (contourarea > 100000) {

                        //Contour Drawing + Bounding Box
                        xBound = rect.x;
                        yBound = rect.y;
                        xWidth = rect.width;
                        yHeight = rect.height;
                        //to Draw contour(colour is in Yellow (red+green))
                        Imgproc.drawContours(oriImage, contours, idx, new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, new Point());
                        //to Draw Outer Bounding rectangle(colour is in Green)
                        Imgproc.rectangle(oriImage, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                                new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);

                        // this if-else block is to get correct Length of the square, i.e smaller length is chosen as length to get perfect square fitting in the circle
                        if (rect.height > rect.width)
                            radius = rect.width/2;
                        else
                            radius = rect.height/2;
                    }
                }

                //To find internal boundary to crop image
                radius = (int)(radius*0.70711);
                int xPos = xBound+(xWidth/2)-radius;
                int yPos = yBound+(yHeight/2)-radius;
                Rect reg_info = new Rect(xPos,yPos,radius*2,radius*2);
                Mat region = oriImage.submat(reg_info);
                //to Draw Inner Bounding rectangle(colour is in Yellow (red+green))
                Imgproc.rectangle(oriImage, new Point(xBound+(xWidth/2)-radius, yBound+(yHeight/2)-radius),
                        new Point(xBound+(xWidth/2)-radius + radius*2, yBound+(yHeight/2)-radius + radius*2), new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 3);


                //Transform RGB to L*a*b* (CIELab)
                Mat imgLab = new Mat();
                Imgproc.cvtColor(region, imgLab, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2Lab);
                //Split L*a*b* to individual channels
                List<Mat> lLab = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
                Core.split(imgLab, lLab);
                Mat mLabL = lLab.get(0);   //L channel
                Mat mLaba = lLab.get(1);   //a* channel
                Mat mLabb = lLab.get(2);   //b* channel

                //Image Otsu from Labb channel image
                //(Binary Thresholding for WBC)
                Mat imgWBC = new Mat();
                Imgproc.threshold(mLabb, imgWBC, 110, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

                Mat imgWBCnew = imgWBC.clone();

                long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
            elapsedSeconds = tDelta/1000.0 ;

            //To convert the Mat object back to Bitmap
            Utils.matToBitmap(oriImage,processBitmap);


          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                  invalidateOptionsMenu();
                  PhotoView myImage = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.resultImage);
                  myImage.setImageBitmap(processBitmap);
                  db.updateResult(new SampleViewList(fileName,folderName,countRBC,countWBC,String.valueOf(elapsedSeconds),getDate()));
                  getImage = db.getImgView(fileName);
                  showResult();
                  try{
                      FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(resultImagedir);
                      processBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                      try{
                          fOut.flush();
                          fOut.close();
                      } catch (IOException E){
                          E.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

    }

    });
            }
  }).start();
    }
```